# How to update same line than insert/update in plpgsql without reaching max_stack_depth

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

My problem is I reach the limit of the stack. And the message error says “You should increase `max_stack_depth`” and shows me the line that I use to update another column.

I encounter this error after an update request (code below).

I know my problem may look like others questions but none of them explain why I reach this error.

What I want to do is simple and I've done it many times, but here I'm missing something.

I want: if there is an update on the table `support_fh` pull a trigger. I expect this trigger to do:

if the new values of the update request are `section`= `'DISTRIBUTION'` and `modulo`= `'6'` and `fabricant` = `'NEXANS'` and `capacite` = `12` then set `diametre` = `'12.5'` (code below).

Of course it is the line of `diametre` from the same line than update request.

Futhermore I know I should use the `character varying` type instead of the `integer` type, but I was asked to so it like that.

My trigger function:

```sql
create or replace function maj_diam() returns trigger
as
$$
Declare fab_loc character varying;
Declare section_loc character varying;
Declare capa_loc character varying;
Declare modulo_loc character varying;

BEGIN
    Select fabricant into fab_loc from support_fh where id = new.id;
    Select section into section_loc from support_fh where id = new.id;
    Select capcite into capa_loc from support_fh where id = new.id;
    Select modulo into modulo_loc from support_fh where id = new.id;

    if fab_loc = 'NEXANS' and section_loc = 'DISTRIBUTION'
       and capa_loc = '12' and modulo_loc = '6' then
        update support_fh set diametre = '12.2' where id = new.id;
    endif;

    return new;
end;
$$;
```

My trigger :

```sql
create trigger maj_diam
After update on support_fh
for each row
execute procedure maj_diam();
```

My update request to test my trigger :

```sql
update support_fh set fabricant = 'NEXANS', section = 'DISTRIBUTION', capacite = '12', modulo = '6' 
where id = 11827;
```

I want to learn from this, so, if possible, explain to me what I'm doing wrong here, or if my approach is lacking insight.

Comment: Why are you storing numbers as varchar values?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i didn't do the db, I'm just helping someone with the triggers. But you're right integer or float should be the right type here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get that problem because the update in the trigger will launch the trigger again, causing an infinite loop. No value of `max_stack_depth` is big enough for that (and increasing that value too much is dangerous anyway).

Instead of what you are doing, you should create a `BEFORE` trigger and modify the `NEW` value that are about to be inserted:

```
IF NEW.fab_loc = 'NEXANS' AND NEW.section_loc = 'DISTRIBUTION'
   AND NEW.capa_loc = '12' AND NEW.modulo_loc = '6'
THEN
   NEW.diametre := '12.2';
END IF;
```

Comment: I thought If I wanted to modify a value from the same line an `AFTER` trigger was needed. My bad ! It makes senses that if the trigger use an update query then it causes an infinite loop. Thank you for your time and answer !

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change columns in a row that is updated (or inserted), don't use `UPDATE` in the trigger function. Declare the trigger as `BEFORE UPDATE`, then simply assign the new values.

You also don't need four select statements to read four columns from the same table.

But as you are only accessing columns from the same row that was updated, you don't even need a SELECT at all.

So your trigger function can be simplified to:

```
create or replace function maj_diam() returns trigger
as
$$
BEGIN
   if new.fabricant = 'NEXANS' 
      and new.section = 'DISTRIBUTION' 
      and new.capcite = '12' 
      and new.modulo = '6' 
   then
     new.diametre := '12.2';
   end if;
   return new;
end;
$$;
```

Assuming that capcite, modulo and diametre are actually numbers, you shouldn't compare them with varchar values. So the above code should probably be: `new.diametre := 12.2;` or `new.capcite = 12`.

And the trigger definition needs to be changed to:

```
create trigger maj_diam
BEFORE update on support_fh
for each row
execute procedure maj_diam();
```